# Can an Augmented triad be called a Quartal chord?

Tags: chords, harmony, analysis

Since a Quartal chord can be defined as diminished, perfect or augmented fourths, can an augmented triad be analysed as a quartal chord with stacked diminished fourths enharmonically?
Also is the chord D/E voiced as E-A-D-F♯ a quartal chord?

Comment: *is the chord D/E voiced as E-A-D-F# a quartal chord*>? wouldn't this be D/E  (inversion)?
aren't only perfect fourths quartal chords? (btw. thank you for the term "quartal chord", I haven't known this expression in English)

Comment: As far as I know, diminished and augmented fourths are allowed in quartal harmony.

Comment: Isn't this going to be based more on how the notes are defined/spelled? C>Fb is  dim4, but will sound like M3. also using aug4ths, C>F# is fine, but going up another aug4th takes us to B#, enharmonic to the original C. What have I missed?

Comment: You're right. We typically hear an augmented chord as two stacked 3rds and not 4ths because when people play it, it's usually in a context where there's just one other note in between the chord tones. (eg. Whole tone scale, Ionian Augmented)

Comment: Are you intentionally spelling the chord `E-A-D-F♯`? Based on the first part of your question `E-A-D-G♭` would seem to be the way to shoehorn it into quartal harmony. From there I think the real question is whether `G♭` is believable in the tonality. Enharmonically it outlines a major triad and DO, RE, MI. Not clear how you will make that _aurally_ sound quartal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would at best be a stretch. Typically in quartal stacks, you only use perfect and augmented 4ths for obvious reasons (diminished 4ths sound like major 3rds in equal temperament). Same goes for quintal as you typically only use diminished and perfect 5ths. When diminished 4ths are used they are used sparingly so trying to do two in a row would very much be an outlier and wherever you are in your stack it will take a more terian harmony turn.

Maybe to put it the best way, there's a whole class of chords called suses which are for when there's no third and it has been replaced by a major 2nd or perfect 4th. You could spell them so you're dealing with a diminished 3rd or augmented 3rd, but they are never interpreted nor spelled that way because they are subverting the terian system not forced inside of it.

This is the same thing with your proposal. While possible, you are bending the spelling and what the typical bounds of what is considered quartal via enharmonics which could be done.

Comment: In tertial harmony, the diminished 5th occurs on the 7th degree of a major scale, and on top of that, all types of alterations are allowed,  augmented 6th chords that denote 3rds that sound as seconds. To get the most out of quartal harmonies, altered notes can and should be allowed, they are not a 'stretch' if the voice leading is logical.

Comment: @user3235 I think you are missing the general point. Quartal harmony was to work outside the typical terian. Trying to make this unique when building stacks of diminished 4ths that can be interpreted as major 3rds defeats the purpose of what someone is trying to accomplish.  When using teran harmony, the diminished 5th is created from two minor 3rds when building chords in 3rds and all the alterations are just that: alterations outside of the normal system which is why they tend to be used.

Comment: Let me try again. Yes, the motivation behind harmonies built off of fourths is for a different sound, BUT ... there is a point at which, unless you're just using one of two measures of fourths, that you need to vary harmonic content. And a diminished 7th is a 6th, misspelled for functional reasons, a parallel to using a flatted or augmented 4th, given the correct resolution of the altered 4th.

Answer (score 8):

In theory whenever there is an ambiguity regarding two notes that are enharmonic equivalents, it can only be resolved with the help of the context. 
For instance a tritone by itself can be a #4 or a b5 but when you play the rest of the notes of the scale, it clears things up. You can make the same note sound like the fourth degree in lydian or the 5th degree in locrian and they both feel very different from each other. In fact just playing the major 3rd would make it feel like lydian (#4), and a minor 3rd would make it sound locrian or diminished (b5).

So in situations like this, try to think what scale your chord comes from. If you say an augmented chord can be considered a quartal chord, it means it contains 2 diminished fourths. So the scale would have to look something like 1 b2 b3 b4 b5 bb6 bbb7. Even if the scale has its name it's got to be so rare that when you hear the augmented chord by itself, you'd much rather see it in the context of the whole tone scale or perhaps lydian augmented. Which are far more common than the monstrosity that that scale is with the bbb7.

Similarly if you're imagining [E-A-D-F#] this chord as a quartal one, firstly you'll have to call the F# a Gb, and then you'd have to visualize a scale which contains [ D E F Gb A ].
You could do that. But I'm pretty sure that it won't be a common scale and it won't be easy to capture the sound of the scale. And in any case, it certainly won't be as easy as hearing the D major scale. As a result when you hear those notes, your brain would much rather hear a F# at the top than a Gb because then that chord appears in numerous common scales.

So to answer your question, in summary, by default they're not to be considered quartal chords, however, you can try to make them sound like one though that could be very difficult.

Comment: If the E-A-D-F# chord is played by itself, it's unclear what the exact note names are. Irrespective of what sounds we are accustomed to (which varies from person to person), chord names often allow for flexibility and enharmonicism. For example, when naming fully diminished 7th chords, note names are freely switched for their enharmonic equivalents. So I think that answers my question. (this example didn't occur to me earlier)

Comment: @JairajPatil, the diminished seventh chord seems like a good example to make the point about enharmonic spelling and the context of the tonic, but not about whether the harmony is tertian or quartal. Respelling `B D F Ab` with tonic of `C` as `B D F G#` with tonic `A` doesn't change the tertian structure. In the same way merely spelling `E-A-D-F#`  as `E-A-D-Gb` won't make it sound quartal.

Comment: @Michael Curtis The OP didn't specifically say anything about making {E,A,D,Gb} sound quartal, though it's unclear what he meant by 'voiced'. In a context that is primarily based on perfect 4ths, with logical voice leading, altered 4ths chords will make sense.

Comment: @user3235, the voicing part is clear. He's using a common jazz voicing arrange the tones as a stack of fourths. The third on top is then the point of the question: does the third make it not "a quartal chord?" Combine that with the question of enharmonic respelling of M3 as d4 to justify calling tertian chords quartal (the premise of his augmented chord idea.) I took the next logical step and did the respelling `E-A-D-Gb`, not because he literally asked that, but because I thought the question hinted in that direction.

Answer (score 8):

There's 'Quartal harmony' and there's 'Quartal voicing'. The first is a conscious attempt to get away from triad-based tonal harmony.  The second is a very standard and unremarkable way of voicing tonal harmonies, particularly when sus4, 9 and/or 13 extensions are used.

Scriabin based whole pieces around this sort of chord, (and he didn't use it as an extended C7!)

[image]

Most pianists would consider using this RH voicing for F13 pretty mainstream.

[image]

Both can be described as 'quartal'.  If you use the term, make sure it's clear which you're talking about!

Answer (score 3):

I tried working out a possible quartal scenario using a diminished fourth, sort of along the lines that @IndroneilKanungo described, creating a scale with `E A D Gb`.

First I compacted the chord and arranged the two fourths by step `D Gb` and `E A`. It seem sensible to add fourths above at `C` (natural because the `G` was already altered) and `B` below (natural to make a P4 with the `E`.) The remaining tone to fill in was `F` (natural to not enharmonically duplicate `E` or `Gb`.)

[image]

Unless I missed something I found only one four voice stack of perfect fourths starting on `B`. I made that the sort-of-tonic and then made two parallel chord lines going up and down to the `B` chord.

[image]

I marked the complete, perfect quartal chord with `*`, the chord with the not-a-third-but-an-diminished-fourth I marked `M`, and two dominant-like chords I marked `D`.

It's interesting how the diminished fourth appears in 3 of the 7 chords with a kind of tertian sound yet there was only one full, perfect fourth chord. In a plain diatonic scale you get 4 out of 7 full, perfect fourth chords.

Would this work as quartal harmony? I don't see why not. But you would probably want to avoid emphasis of the tertian tinged chords.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know. But as you ask:

> Can an Augmented triad be called a Quartal chord?

The answer is: Yes, we can.

somewhere even the **Tristan chord** is mentioned as a the root of the  quartal chords:

***The bottom two notes make up an augmented fourth, while the upper two make up a perfect fourth.** This layering of fourths in this context has been seen as highly significant. The chord had been found in earlier works (Vogel 1962, 12), notably Beethoven's Piano Sonata No. 18, but Wagner's use was significant, first because it is seen as moving away from traditional tonal harmony and even towards atonality, and second because with this chord Wagner actually provoked the sound or structure of musical harmony to become more predominant than its function, a notion which was soon after to be explored by Debussy and others.*

**But the opinions differ:**

*Despite the layering of fourths, it is rare to find musicologists identifying this chord as "quartal harmony" or even as "proto-quartal harmony", since Wagner's musical language is still essentially built on thirds, and **even an ordinary dominant seventh chord can be laid out as augmented fourth plus perfect fourth (F–B–D–G)**. Wagner's unusual chord is really a device to draw the listener into the musical-dramatic argument which the composer is presenting to us.*

*At the beginning of the 20th century, quartal harmony finally became an important element of harmony. **Scriabin** used a self-developed system of transposition using fourth-chords, like his Mystic chord (shown below) in his **Piano Sonata No. 6.***

[image]

Read more about **Quartal chords**:

[Quartal and quintal harmony (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartal_and_quintal_harmony)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't quartal chords supposed to be comprised entirely by stacking fourths? In the Tristan chord since there is a third between the middle voices, it shouldn't be considered a quartal chord.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the tristan chord is built by a 3rd. I will delete this example.